# serialise php session variables into json format

Tags: php, json, session

I want to access PHP session variables through jQuery. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

Be careful what you store in the session though. ;)

Comment: On one hand, this is completely correct.  On the other hand, this is a horrible, horrible idea.  On the third hand, if the OP really wants this, then he or she gets what she or he deserves.  On the fourth hand *why do I have more than two hands*.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zhangjiayin/php_session_json_handler/

PHP EXTENSION FOR SESSION WITH JSON FORMAT SAERIALIZE

config php.ini

session.serialize_handler = json

maybe help you,try it?